# Node JS API failed to fetch data

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, next.js

I have recently made an API using express and MongoDB, everything works fine with postman until I use it in my Next JS app with the help of `fetch()`. The normal GET requests are working but POST requests don't seem to work. It returns a cors error even though I have added the cors library into the API. Here is the code from the next js app:

```js
import { SparklesIcon, QuestionMarkCircleIcon } from '@heroicons/react/24/solid'

export default function Home () {
    function getData () {
        fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/auth/login', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: {
                email: "ceo-jedidiah@xenon-inc.in",
                password: "M!nnu2009"
            }
        }).then(res => res.json()).then(data => {
            console.log(data)
        })
    }

    return (
        <div className="w-screen h-screen bg-black text-white font-poppins">
            <nav className="w-screen h-14 px-4 flex flex-row items-center justify-center border-white select-none relative">
                    <img src="/logo.svg" alt="" className="w-10 h-10 rounded-full" />
                    <h1 className="font-bold ml-2 text-2xl text-white font-nunito mr-auto">Xenon</h1>
                    <ul className="flex flex-row">
                        <li className="m-4 opacity-50 hover:opacity-100 transition-all cursor-pointer">About Us</li>
                        <li className="m-4 opacity-50 hover:opacity-100 transition-all cursor-pointer">Explore</li>
                        <li className="m-4 opacity-50 hover:opacity-100 transition-all cursor-pointer">Services</li>
                        <li className="m-4 opacity-50 hover:opacity-100 transition-all cursor-pointer">Products</li>
                        <li className="m-4 opacity-50 hover:opacity-100 transition-all cursor-pointer">Pricing</li>
                        <li className="m-4 opacity-50 hover:opacity-100 transition-all cursor-pointer">API</li>
                    </ul>
                    <button className="py-1 px-3 bg-white border-2 border-white hover:bg-black hover:text-white transition-all text-black rounded-md ml-4 text-sm" onClick={getData}>Sign Up</button>
            </nav>
            <main>
                <section className="w-screen h-[calc(100vh-56px)] flex flex-col items-center justify-center">
                    <h1 className="text-8xl font-black text-indigo-500">Think.</h1>
                    <h1 className="text-8xl font-black text-blue-500">Build.</h1>
                    <h1 className="text-8xl font-black text-green-500">Publish.</h1>
                    <p className="w-[1150px] text-center mt-4 text-zinc-600 text-2xl">Xenon is a platform to hire someone to build you something at very cheap and affordable prices. Also you can showcase your own work on the explore page.</p>
                    <div className="flex flex-row items-center justify-center mt-8">
                        <button className="py-2 px-20 bg-white border-2 border-white hover:bg-black hover:text-white transition-all text-black rounded-md ml-4 text-md flex flex-row items-center justify-center"><SparklesIcon className='w-6 mr-2' /> Get Started</button>
                        <button className="py-2 px-20 bg-black border-2 border-white hover:bg-white hover:text-black text-white transition-all rounded-md ml-4 text-md flex flex-row items-center justify-center"><QuestionMarkCircleIcon className='w-6 mr-2' /> Learn More</button>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </main>
        </div>
    )
}
```

The error in browser:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWCT9.png)

Im trying to use the login method on my API which should return an object with the json web token and user data

Comment: *I have added the cors library into the API* - consider showing that part.

Comment: CORS are ignored in postman, which can explain why you had no issues. Can you share your server code? (at least setting up cors middleware)?

Comment: app.use(cors({
    origin: ['http://localhost:3000']
}))

Comment: The screenshot says that your web page is at `localhost:3001` so you need to allow CORS from `localhost:3001`

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure if you add cors like this in the API

```
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors({
  origin: ['Your first url', 'Your second url if you have ..']
}));
```

probably you will use http://localhost:3000.

one thing more. If you already all those above. Try use axios instead of fetch
you can checkout the axios documentation from [here](https://axios-http.com/docs/intro) it's more safe and usable library for fetching.

## Update

try to send your data like this with `JSON.stringify({your data ..})`.

```
function getData () {
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/auth/login', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            email: "ceo-jedidiah@xenon-inc.in",
            password: "M!nnu2009"
        })
    }).then(res => res.json()).then(data => {
        console.log(data)
    })
}
```

Comment: I have tried this and all routes seem to work except my login route. Code: https://pastebin.com/zt3aD2wW. Please let me know if something is wrong in here

Comment: Sorry, but the url didn't work.

Comment: The error message in the screenshot says that origin is `localhost:3001` so it definitely should not be `localhost:3000`

Comment: @slebetman Yep. Right

Comment: yes but i had changed the port of the express app to `5000` and the next js app is running on port `3000`

Comment: @HamudeShahin try this https://gist.github.com/jedidiahp/36796d6942fa172fb31d81968718c44c